# How can you store user input within a loop without overwriting?

Tags: python, loops

I'm having a user input info for a program and I'm having trouble storing information from user without it overwriting in a loop. My code as follows:

```
def main():
    total_circles = input("Enter the number of circles: ")
    for number in range(1, int(total_circles) + 1):
        circles = input("Enter the radius of circle {}: ".format(number))
        circle_value = float(circles)
    circle_value = [] + [circle_value]
```

Is there a way to store each radii input into a variable to be added into the list `cValue`?

Output:

```
Enter the number of circles: 2
Enter the radius of circle 1: 7
Enter the radius of circle 2: 4
```

Comment: `circle_value.append(float(circles))` should do the trick instead of `circle_value = float(circles)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to initialize a list to append the values to before you enter the loop:

```
def main():
    total_circles = input("Enter the number of circles: ")
    circles = []
    for number in range(1, int(total_circles) + 1):
        circles.append(float(input("Enter the radius of circle {}: ".format(number))))
    print(circles)
```

If you run the program with the following input:

```
Enter the number of circles: 2
Enter the radius of circle 1: 5
Enter the radius of circle 2: 7
```

The output will be

```
[5.0, 7.0]
```

And the individual values on that list can be accessed like this:

```
circles[0]  # 5.0, the value of circle 1 (stored at index 0)
circles[1]  # 7.0, the value of circle 2 (stored at index 1)
```

Comment: thank you. appreciate the answer. I figured if i did `.append()` it would have done the same but now I know.

Comment: @Compscistudent Nearly. If you had initialized a list to save the circle values in prior to the loop (call it `circle_values` if you like), then instead of `circle_values.append(circle_value)` *inside the loop* you could also write `circle_values += [circle_value]` to accomplish the appending.